# Error when joining other communities

Tags: support, bug

I receive the famous "Oops! Something Bad Happened!", when trying to join gamedev community with my account. Has anyone else had this problem recently? I have joined stackoverflow quite recently and today this happened.

Comment: I was only able to find an error about attempting to join a site from meta here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/269699/join-this-community-gives-404-when-called-from-add-comment-on-a-site-meta/269708 Not sure if that's related to your problem.

Comment: Did it happen more than once? (any console output if it continues to happen?)

Comment: It looks like this is also being reported on MSE at the moment: [Can't join a community](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/277116/cant-join-a-community) Check the "Linked" sidebar for others- I'd say that yes, others do appear to be having this issue.